# Using .trimend() in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, trim

I am really new to PowerShell. I am trying to use [`.TrimEnd(", ")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend).

How do I have it trim the end *only* if the characters `", "` exist at the end? And to skip otherwise?

I have looked online, but I could not find any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TrimEnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=net-7.0) and the other trim methods from the [`String` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0) will remove any appearance of **any of the characters passed as argument** so in this case, these methods will not solve your issue. You could definitely use [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) in this case and by doing so there wouldn't be a need to check if the string ends with `,`  just let the regex replacement operator handle that for you.

```
'string, ' -replace ', $'
```

See https://regex101.com/r/cLCgC3/1 for details and a more visualized representation of what this means.

Comment: Hi! this would work but I only want to do this at the end of the string. Is there a way to make it so it only replaces the end?

Comment: @Jasmine this is exactly doing that. give it a try. `$` in regex means end of the line, so it will only target and remove " ," only if it is at the end of the line

Comment: @Jasmine, given that Santiago's answer verifiably solves your problem,  please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248777) it or providing feedback, if your question isn't fully answered yet.