# PowerShell Trim is trimming more than it should

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out why the following PowerShell code ends up with $manifestObj.name being *Microsoft Power Automa* instead of *Microsoft Power Automate*.  The full code actually gets all the extension folders for the Chrome profile via a foreach loop, but this example produces the same issue.

```
$manifestObj = New-Object System.Object

$manifestJSON = Get-Content "C:\Users\<MyUserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\ljglajjnnkapghbckkcmodicjhacbfhk\2.27.0.2_0\manifest.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$manifestObj = New-Object System.Object
#get name and version from json and add to object
$manifestObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $manifestJSON.name
$manifestObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Version -Value $manifestJSON.version

$url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ljglajjnnkapghbckkcmodicjhacbfhk"
$stringToTrim = " - Chrome Web Store"

$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$data = $webClient.downloadstring($url)
#scrape the title
$titleTag = [regex] '(?<=<title>)([\S\s]*?)(?=</title>)'
#trim the title
$title = $titleTag.Match($data).value.trim()
$manifestObj.name = $title.Trim($stringToTrim)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647346/using-trimend-in-powershell/74647478#74647478

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding what .trim() does.  The character order doesn't matter.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0 Maybe use replace() instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Using Replace fixed the issue.  I assumed something was wrong as the Power Automate extension was the only one not being trimmed as I expected.